# After enabling Zuul proxy for the Spring boot app (We have set of miroservices), spring mvc interceptor doesnot work

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

Below is the Application.java. It has code to invoke the interceptor

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenValidateInterceptor tokenValidateInterceptor() {
        TokenValidateInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new TokenValidateInterceptor();
        System.out.println("In WEB MVC Intereptor, Interceptor returned");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("In WEB MVC Intereptor");
        // registry.addInterceptor(tokenValidateInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/");
        registry.addInterceptor(tokenValidateInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/**");
        // registry.addInterceptor(new
        // TokenValidateInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/**");
    }

}
```

Below is the snippet of the interceptor code:

```
@Component
public class TokenValidateInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TokenValidateInterceptor.class);

    // before the actual handler will be executed ..
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        String apikey = request.getHeader("apikey");
        // if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.info("#### Starting TokenValidateInterceptor.preHandle ####");
        LOG.info("apikey-->" + apikey);
        // }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(apikey) || apikey == null || apikey.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
        }
}
}
```

But the call does not reach prehandle of the interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, all requests that are defined in Zuul routing are handled by `ZuulServlet`. 
Spring MVC doesn't handle these requests, so any Spring `HandlerInterceptor` will not be called for these requests. If you need any preprocessing for API requests, you should implement it in Zuul prefilter or servlet filter.